# How to access a component from a service in Angular 7

Tags: angular, primeng, angular-services

I use the PrimeNG library in an Angular 7 application and I'm curious about how they've implemented a feature. I'll try to explain it:

One of its components is 'Toast', that shows short messages with a pop-up style, like this:

[image]

For it to work, you need to define a `p-toast` component in the template:

```
<p-toast></p-toast>
```

And provide a global `MessageService` to show the message, using this method:

```
this.messageService.add({severity:'success', summary:'Service Message', detail:'Via MessageService'});
```

My question is, how do they find the `p-toast` component from the `add` method in the `MessageService` service? For example, I have inserted the `p-toast` in the `app-component.html` template and I can use the `messageService.add` from all the components of the application, no matter the hierarchy. NOTE: I also declare the `MessageService` in the `providers` section of the `app.module.ts` file, to make the service global.

I hope it's understandable... thanks!

Comment: this add methods does nothing but pushes an object to the Array of type `Message` . It exists inside the p-toast component . Once the value is pushed it uses a Rxjs `Subject` to emit and broadcast the message to all the subscribers. There is one such subscriber in p-toast . Hence you get the updated value in the component.

Comment: Thanks! That cleared my doubt. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You need to create customize service and subscribe it to show toast. [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fjbo25)

customize-message.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomizeMessageService {

  private loaderSubject = new Subject<MessageState>();
  loaderState = this.loaderSubject.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  show() {
    this.loaderSubject.next(<MessageState>{ show: true });
  }

}

export interface MessageState {
  show: boolean;
}
```

app.component.html

```
<p-toast [style]="{marginTop: '80px'}"></p-toast>
```

app.component.ts

```
constructor(private messageService: MessageService, private loaderService: CustomizeMessageService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loaderService.loaderState.subscribe((state: MessageState) => {
      if (state.show) {
      this.messageService.add({severity:'success', summary: 'Success Message', detail:'Order submitted'});
      }
    });
  }
```

another.component.ts

```
constructor(private customizeMessageService: CustomizeMessageService) {}
showToast() {
    this.customizeMessageService.show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by the answers, each `p-toast` component has a subscriber of the global service `MessageService` to receive the messages to be displayed.